# Jenkins get/set data external to job

Tags: jenkins

Does jenkins have any way to set global properties from a job?   We have many such needs for this - but specifically - we have a number of slaves, across unix and windows, and various different permissions locations - so it's not easy to have a connected file system.   We have various levels of maturity that we promote through - so for instance, we want to promote some build number to UAT - and then promote *whatever number is in UAT* to training and so on.  So - really, in the "release to uat" - we want to store some idea of which build number was released - and read that from the "release to training" job.    At the moment we are hacking it by restricting them to run from the same slave, and writing it to a file, which is very much not ideal.

Answer (score 1):

I may not have totally understood your question but you can perform a lot of work with the built in groovy scripting function in jenkins, including reading parameters from other jobs, and *rewriting* or initializing the parameters in the current job. You can use parameters like this to record information that can be retrieved on demand by other jobs

For instance you can find the build number of the last successful build of a certain project:

```
import hudson.model.*
def hif = Hudson.instance

def a = hif.getItems(hudson.model.Project).find{it.displayName.toUpperCase()=='MY_PROJECTNAME'}.getBuilds().findAll{it.result==Result.SUCCESS }.first()
out.println a.number //build number
out.println a.buildVariableResolver.resolve('someVariable')// some parameter used to call a
```

(you could include any other criteria at this point)

If you want to save information to a parameter that can later be read by another bulid step or another job then you first create the parameter in the job config, then write to it in code like so:

```
import hudson.model.*
def hif = Hudson.instance
def buildMap = build.getBuildVariables() 

buildMap['MySpecialVar']='SomeValue'

setBuildParameters(buildMap)

def setBuildParameters(map) {
    def npl = new ArrayList<StringParameterValue>()
    for (e in map) {
        npl.add(new StringParameterValue(e.key.toString(), e.value.toString()))
    }
    def newPa = null
    def oldPa = build.getAction(ParametersAction.class)
    if (oldPa != null) {
        build.actions.remove(oldPa)
        newPa = oldPa.createUpdated(npl)
    } else {
        newPa = new ParametersAction(npl)
    }
    build.actions.add(newPa)
}
```

Combining these techniques you could for instance:

1. Save a bunch of information as 'output parameters' in job one
2. Find the most recent successful instance of job one and read its parameters
3. If necessary save those parameters to job2's parameter list so they are accessible from other build steps.

**OR**

If you are happy to use files then you may be able to use the archive plugin, where you would write to a file and then archive it as a post build action.  The file would be saved to the master, and you could use the 'copy artifacts from another project' option in the second build to retrieve the file.  You can use parameter filters and the techniques above to pick the right build.

Answer (score 0):

Setting an environment variable permanently is entirely dependent on the underlying Operating System.

For example on Windows, the [**SetX**](http://ss64.com/nt/setx.html) command can be used, however note that SetX only takes affect after the next process is created by the system the inherits from global configuration. So, if you run SetX, and then run another job, it will not notice the change. However if you run SetX, and then restart Jenkins process (from which all child jobs inherit variables), then the other job will notice the change.

Not sure how to set permanent variables in Linux, but a quick Google search returns this answer: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/117467/how-to-permanently-set-environmental-variables

Comment: thanks, but the problem is - I want the variable accessible across multiple slaves, so it has to be something in jenkins, not something on the system